# Find the longest path of all shortest pathes in a graph (32 thousand vertexes)

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm doing my laboratory work, and I need to solve a task. The text of it:

Byteland's rail network consists of N stations, numbered from 1 to N, connected by N-1 two-way rail tracks. Each railway track connects exactly two different stations and has a certain length in kilometers. A route is a sequence of stations in which each station occurs exactly once and all neighboring stations in this sequence are connected by railways. The length of a route is the sum of the lengths of all railway tracks connecting neighboring stations in the appropriate sequence. For any two Byteland stations, there is always at least one route linking them. Your task is to determine the magnitude of Byteland's longest route.

So, now I'm using Dijsktra algoritm optimized using std::set to find the shortest path between two vertexes of a graph. The solution must find the answer in 1 second and use less than 130mb of memory. The hardest test has 32 thousand vertexes and my code solves it in 660 seconds which is not enough. What can I do to improve my solution?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graph.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Используйте: LW2 [path]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Graph myGraph(argv[1]);

    std::cout << "Максимальное расстояние: " << myGraph.getMaxDistanceOfAll() << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Graph.h:

```
#ifndef LW2_GRAPH_H
#define LW2_GRAPH_H

#include "vector"
#include "string"

class Graph {
private:

    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> adjacencyList;

    int addVertice();

    void addEdge(int where, int what, int weight);

public:
    [[maybe_unused]] explicit Graph(const std::string & path);

    int getDistance(int vStart);

    int getMaxDistanceOfAll();

    int size();

};


#endif //LW2_GRAPH_H
```

Graph.cpp:

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

#include "set"

#include "thread"
#include "future"

[[maybe_unused]] Graph::Graph(const std::string & path) {
    std::ifstream fin(path);

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open this file." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int count;
    fin >> count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        addVertice();

    do {
        int x, y, z;
        fin >> x >> y >> z;
        addEdge(x-1, y-1, z);
    } while (!fin.eof());

    fin.close();
}

int Graph::addVertice() {   // Добавляем вершину в список
    adjacencyList.emplace_back(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>());
    return adjacencyList.size() - 1;
}


void Graph::addEdge(int where, int what, int weight) {
    adjacencyList[where].emplace_back(std::make_pair(what, weight));
    adjacencyList[what].emplace_back(std::make_pair(where, weight));
}


int Graph::getDistance(int vStart) {

    // 15 sec

    std::vector<int> d(size(), INT32_MAX);
    d[vStart] = 0;

    auto cmp = [&d](int a, int b) {
        return d[a] > d[b];
    };

    std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);

    queue.insert(vStart);

    int max = 0;
    while (!queue.empty()) {

        int v = *queue.begin();
        queue.erase(queue.begin());

        for (size_t j = 0; j < adjacencyList[v].size(); ++j) {

            int to = adjacencyList[v][j].first,
                len = adjacencyList[v][j].second;

            if (d[v] + len < d[to]) {
                queue.erase(to);
                d[to] = d[v] + len;
                if (d[to] > max)
                    max = d[to];
                queue.insert(to);
            }
        }

    }

    return max;

}

int Graph::getMaxDistanceOfAll() {

    // unsigned int maxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    std::vector<std::future<int>> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if (adjacencyList[i].size() == 1) {
            threads.emplace_back(
                    std::async(std::launch::async, &Graph::getDistance, this, i)
                    );
        }
    }

    int max = 0;
    for (auto & thread : threads) {
        int res = thread.get();
        if (res > max)
            max = res;
    }

    return max;

}

int Graph::size() {
    return adjacencyList.size();
}
```

Comment: Where does the "shortest path" requirement come from? As far as I understand the assignment, you are supposed to find the sequence of connected stations without repetition (route) that has the longest total length.

Comment: Question: How does a graph with N vertices and N-1 edges look like for all vertices to be connected. Hint: It does have a name.

Comment: @Quimby Sorry, didn't see your comment before posting, now I deleted it

Comment: This is basically a math problem rather than a programming problem. Once you answer the question asked by @quimby the solution becomes much easier.

Comment: @Quimby oh, I get it. So, it's a tree?

Comment: @РостиславЛипский Yup, Rocco recognized it too :]

Comment: @Quimby  I am not fully sure about your statement. A tree has a root and leaves. If you have a graph "8--3--5" it has n verteices and n-1 edges. Besides that it does not matter for the shown case, where is the root ?  8 or 3 or 5? Maybe we need to think more . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny That graph is a tree. No, tree graphs do not have a unique root, in fact, any vertex can be designated as root.  No, it does not matter which vertex is a root for this problem. Of course it matters if you want to represent the graph as a recursive structure, but you can pick any.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Quimby and @Rocco!

So, according to the task we have N vertexes and N-1 edges. That means that we have a tree and it makes the task much easier to solve.

All we need to do is to find a diameter of tree (the longest of the shortest pathes in a tree).

I've changed my function with Dijsktra's algorithm in order to find the most distant vertex from given vertex and return pair:

```
std::pair<int, int> Graph::getDistance(int vStart) {

    std::vector<int> d(size(), INT32_MAX);
    d[vStart] = 0;

    auto cmp = [&d](int a, int b) {
        return d[a] > d[b];
    };

    std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);

    queue.insert(vStart);

    std::pair<int, int> result(0, 0);

    while (!queue.empty()) {

        int v = *queue.begin();
        queue.erase(queue.begin());

        for (size_t j = 0; j < adjacencyList[v].size(); ++j) {

            int to = adjacencyList[v][j].first,
                len = adjacencyList[v][j].second;

            if (d[v] + len < d[to]) {
                queue.erase(to);
                d[to] = d[v] + len;
                if (d[to] > result.second)
                    result = make_pair(to, d[to]);
                queue.insert(to);
            }
        }

    }

    return result;

}
```

And then made a function that finds a diameter of a tree according to some algorithm I've found on the net:

```
int Graph::getTreeDiameter() {

    std::pair<int, int> d = getDistance(0);
    d = getDistance(d.first);
    return d.second;

}
```

You can find full code on my [github](https://github.com/ungaf/bsuir/tree/main/%5BPiOIvIS%5D/Semester%202/LW2).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The diameter will normaly only count the nodes. With edges having a weight, the diameter may not show the longest path. Maybe you need to do the naive approach with a double DFS and back tracking.

Comment: @ArminMontigny I've found different definitions to the diameter of a tree, for my task I suppose that diameter means the longest of the shortest paths between two leafs.